# Determining the exact time a photo was taken using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a question of precision.
I have a number of images (photographs) taken during an experiment. I would like to mark the times that the picture were taken on a plot. To get the file information I am using:

```
fileinfo = dir('myfile.jpg')

fileinfo = 
   name: 'myfile.jpg'
   date: '16-Mar-2006 13:34:01' %My problem is here!!
  bytes: 251
  isdir: 0
datenum: 7.3275e+005
```

The photos were taken in quick succession and I would like to get decimal accuracy but Matlab is rounding it to the nearest second. 
Any ideas how to get something like `13:34:01.34`. Is the `datenum` more accurate? Thanks

Comment: Is the datenum more accurate ?  It certainly might be, have you tried extracting it from the `fileinfo` structure and inspecting it more closely ?

Comment: I have @HighPerformanceMark but when I convert it back to datevector format (something I can understand) it still doesn't have the accuracy

Comment: The seconds component of a Matlab datevec includes a fractional part.  If, when you convert the datenum to a datevec the seconds has fractional part equal to 0 that rather suggests that the sub-second precision you seek is not available from your jpg file.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark In Picasa 3 there is a "Modified Date" which does have sub-second precision and "File Date" which doesn't. I suspect that its the file date that is returned by `dir`. If this is the case is there anyway to get the Modified Date?

Comment: I think that `fileinfo.datenum` is the file date/time from the o/s and depends on your o/s and file system for its precision.  What that might be I don't know.  Nor do I know whether the metadata in a jpeg includes the time the image was created at sub-second resolution.  But the format is well documented and I'm sure a little Googling will answer that question for you.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions

1. plot the `datenum` values of all your photos and see if it makes sense

   ```
   >> fls = dir( '*.jpg' ); % list all files
   >> plot( [fls(:).datenum], '-+'); % see if all images has unique datenum
   ```
2. You might have additional information stored in [exif](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exifread.html)

   ```
   >> xif = exifread( 'myfile.jpg' )
   ```

Comment: Thank. I took your suggestion but the files do not have a unique datenum

Comment: @user1002744 - if this is the case, it appears as if the time intervals between the shots is smaller than `eps( fileinfo.datenum )` - the machine precision at that moment. Check exif data if there is a more accurate info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the command `imfinfo` instead of the information returned by `dir`? `imfinfo` returns a structure containing the EXIF data of the image file, which I believe includes more detailed information on the time the image was taken, in the field `ImageModTime`.

In older versions of MATLAB, use the command `exifread` instead of `imfinfo`.

Comment: imfinfo certainly does have have more information but it still is not decimal accuraty

Comment: I looked a little deeper - I thought there might be a way to modify the internals of `imfinfo`, to change the output format of some call to `datestr`. Unfortunately as you dig in further, you find that the information returned by `imfinfo` is collected by the mex file `matlabroot\toolbox\matlab\imagesci\private\imjpg8.mexw64`, which is unmodifiable. Sorry.